# Installing GPU Drivers from Laptop Vendor or Intel/Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, display-driver

I have an Intel iGPU/Nvidia dGPU laptop running Windows 10 and was wondering if it was better to use the drivers form my laptop's manufacturer (Overpowered (Model 17+)) or those provided by Intel/Nvidia. The dillema comes from the fact that the drivers provided by my laptop's vendor have not been updated for a while. My main interest is gaming performance.

NOTES:

Laptop:

Overpowered 17+

-CPU: i7 8750H

-GPU: GTX 1060 (notebook)

Answer (score 0):

You should update drivers according to specific parts vendor(Intel/Nvidia).

In your case Nvidia/Intel provides new better performance updated drivers which pc single manufacturer dont provide and this affect gaming mostly

You can install latest drivers from Intel/Nvidia website and Windows Update

Comment: Those driver update programs are mostly scams. Please don't recommend them.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am using a vpn maybe that is blacklisted not sure.So as I can see I did not post any spam sir you can see my chats in 3 chats rooms.Do this chat ban due to ip address count towards permanent ban of chatting by my account or only by that ip?

Comment: I think it's only by that IP, but I'm not completely sure.